# AngularJS application works only if hit F5

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an application that doesn't work on navigation, but only if I hit F5. My HTML frame:

```
   <html>
      <head>
         <script src="static/vendor/angular.js"></script>
         <script src="static/js/myApplication.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
         <div ng-app="myApp">
            <div ng-controller="GeneralController">
               ...
            </div>
         </div>
      </body>
   </html>
```

My Javascript frame:

```
angular.module('myApp',[])

    .controller('GeneralController',function($scope,$http,$timeout,$sce) {

        $scope.data = {};

        var load = function() {
            $http.get('services/loadData.php')
                .success(function(res) {
                    $scope.data = res;
                    // more code
                 });
            };
        load();

        // more code
     });
```

It was working normally, but now only after hit F5, not on navigation. Naturally, it has many more code, other libraries that I excluded for brevity. After the page is loaded, it renders the output showing de brackets, and don't make the $http request.

Comment: I was a error on post the question. It's correct now.

Comment: Does the JavaScript console report any errors?

Comment: Nothing is reported. The console s blank

Comment: Did you clear your browsers cache?

Comment: Brett answer should do the trick one more thing you can do is try initiating your app in html tag. I am not sure but you can try

Comment: How can I initiate my application in html tag and let the maximum portion of code possible in the external javascript file?

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it, the way your code is written, the `load()` function only runs once when the controller is created. I assume that the Angular framework is not re-instantiating your controller. So, no matter how many times you navigate to this controller, it will only `load()` once. I would refactor your code.

The best option I see is you could use is the `$roueProvider.resolve` function of your route. See the [API documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider).

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']).config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'index.html',
    controller: 'GeneralController',
    resolve: {
      // I will load data from the server and inject it into the controller
      data: function($q, $http) {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        $http.get('services/loadData.php').success(function(res) {
          defer.resolve(res);
        });
       return defer.promise;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

This will inject the `data` property into your `GeneralController` and you can bind it to its scope.

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('GeneralController', function ($scope, data) {
  $scope.data = data;
});
```

Thus, every time a user is routed to your `GeneralController`, a call to `'services/loadData.php'` will occur when route navigation begins.

**Update**: I wrote out this answer and then realized you're not using `ngRoute`. So, you can probably ignore this suggestion. However, I won't delete it, just in case you do. :/

Comment: Your answer is perfect and very useful in the context you described, but I think this is not my problem. My application is simple and have only a view. So, when I say navigate, I  mean arrive to the page from another page that don't use angularjs. I want it load the data only once. The fact is that sometimes the angular not runs (I'd added console.log after opening the controller and it didn't output anything). No errors. In other times it runs normally. I'd clear the cache. There's a problem preventing my application running.

Comment: @EnioCarvalho I'd recommend having the Network and Console tabs of your browser's dev tools (F12) open when you navigate to your app from another site. It sounds like a dependency your code relies on is either taking too long to load the first time, or something else is breaking. It might not be Angular that's the cause.

Comment: I'm working in localhost. All files are being loaded normally. But I think you're right when you say the problem is not releated with angular. Thank you anyway.